# Add variable to JSON_SET path in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set path as a variable?

//Works

```
select json_set('[{"k":"1"}]','$[0].k',23);
```

//Doesn't Work

```
set @p = '$[0].k';
select json_set('[{"k":"1"}]',@p,23);
```

For simplicity, I set path as @p variable. Otherwise, it comes from a WITH JSON_SERARCH. But if variable works, I believe that should work too.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/lfaiC1gf

Comment: Error message? Server version?

Comment: strange not working in my Workbench with mysql 8.1.0. But is working in fbfiddle . thanks @Akina

Comment: *not working in my Workbench with mysql 8.1.0.* Test using CLI.